# How do I open protocols and ports between two hosts

Tags: raspbian, cluster, docker

I am trying to configure my Docker Swarm Cluster and need to have the following ports open so that my cluster can communicate and operate correctly:

- TCP port 2377
- TCP port and UDP port 7946
- UDP port 4789

How do I open these ports?

I believe this is the issue that are causing my worker node to be `DOWN`

Comment: Typing `sudo iptables --list` will show you the open ports. From what I have read [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=24237) and [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69123/how-to-open-a-port), the raspberry Pi does not have any firewall rules in place by default, so the problem is more likey to be with the other devices in question.

Comment: Thank you, yes you're right after looking I found that my two docker nodes were connected to two different networks...

Comment: So the correct answer is: "connect them to the same network"... ;)

Comment: Haha Yes it is 